# query utilizando Case when

Tags: mysql

Alguém consegue me ajudar com essa query por favor? estou tendo dificuldades na hora de organizar esse 'Case when' creio eu

```
CREDITO | CONTA | TIPO
100         8    ENTRADA
30          9    ENTRADA
30         10    ENTRADA
1           8    SAIDA
10         11    ENTRADA
1           8    SAIDA
1          11    SAIDA
10         12    ENTRADA
15         12    ENTRADA
15         13    ENTRADA
```

olha onde quero chegar, é a primeira vez que tento uma query mais diferente, digamos assim.

```
select c, sum(pos), sum(negat) from(
select conta as c,
Case when (tipo = 'ENTRADA') then sum(credito) end pos,
Case when (tipo = 'SAIDA') then sum(credito) end negat
from credito
) A group by c;
```

eu preciso pegar todas as contas num distinct e na mesma linha ter a lista

```
Conta | TotalCreditosEntrada | TotalCreditosSaida
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa fazer uma `query` diferente, o básico já resolve:

```
SELECT a.conta, SUM(IF(a.tipo = 'ENTRADA', a.credito, 0)) AS pos, SUM(IF(a.tipo = 'SAIDA', a.credito, 0)) AS negat
FROM credito AS a
GROUP BY a.conta;
```

O `IF` verifica qual o tipo da operação, se for `ENTRADA` na coluna `pos` estará o valor e na coluna `negat` estará `0`. Caso seja `SAIDA` ocorrerá exatamente o contrário.

Já o `SUM` irá somar todas as linhas e o `GROUP BY` fará a separação pelo número da conta.